# Стоит ли обновлять sphinx

Tags: sphinx

Добрый день. Недавно мне было поручено создание индекса для поиска по вордовским файлам, я планирую использовать для этого postgresql + spinx, но у меня тут же возникает вопрос апгрейда sphinx, т.к. на боевом сервере установлена версия 0.99, я хотел бы узнать, стоит ли мне обновлять его до последней версии и какие преимущества я могу получить от этого.

Comment: главный принцип - работает - не трогай.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> я хотел бы узнать, стоит ли мне обновлять его до последней версии и какие преимущества я могу получить от этого

Кто ж это может решить за вас? Соображения могут быть такими:

1. Что устраивает или не устраивает в работе текущей версии
2. Какие изменения в следующих версиях, как они могут повлиять на работу текущей
3. Есть ли в новых версиях критические обновления, связанные, например, с безопасностью
4. Изменились ли требования к языку запросов, к железу, не утеряна ли обратная совместимость
5. (6,7,8... - по вашим потребностям)

Начать можно, например, [отсюда](http://sphinxsearch.com/bugs/changelog_page.php).

Comment: Пожалуй что действительно стоит обновить, к тому же серьезных агрументов против нет.